# The type or namespace Essentials does not exist in a new Xamarin forms project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I just created a new Xamarin Forms for only android system.

Then two project are created, Xamarin and Xamarin.Android.

When I try to compile, I get the error that the type or namespace does not exist in the Xamarin project.

However, in the packages in the Xamarin project I can see that there is the Xamarin.Essentials.

Also, in the Xamarin.Android project, in the references MonoAndroid, System, System.Core, System.Xml and others has a yellow triangle.

The target android version is Android 12, the default.

I just tried to create the project and compile, I don't do anything more; and I can't see which is the problem.

How could I compile the android project?

Thanks.

Comment: try "Restore Nuget packages" on the entire solution.  If that doesn't work, try removing the individual nugets and re-adding them

Comment: Sometimes, switching to **Release** configuration and then back to **Debug** can solve this type of problems...

Comment: Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

Add `global::` prefix to Xamarin.Essentials. This worked for me